# Get value for javascript from input="number"

Tags: javascript, dom

I have tried everything I can find on here and all over the Internet and this just will not work.

I simply want to check the input type="number" to see if it matches a number already in the database. For now I have kept it simple as I can work out the rest.

Here is my code:

The Input:

```
 <input style="width: 50px; font-size: 17px;" type="number" min="1" autocomplete="off" id="days" name="days" value="1" onchange="daysChange(this.days)" required />
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
 function daysChange(days) {
     var day = document.getElementById("days");
     if (day == "3"){
         alert("You Already Have An Email Going Out That Day. Please Select Another Day.");
     }
 }
```

It's not picking up the value of days. Instead if I do an alert and have it output the value this is what it says... `[object HTMLInputElement]`

Comment: Try `day.value`. `if (day.value == "3"){}`.

Comment: day has the html element in it. You need to get the value in that element. as mentioned by the above comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get value:

```
function daysChange(days) {
 var day = document.getElementById("days");
 if (day.value == "3"){
 alert("You Already Have An Email Going Out That Day. Please Select Another Day.");
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned guys above, `document.getElementById("days")` returns the whole object of matched input. You need to get `value` attribute to get the current input value. Working example:

```js
function daysChange(days) {
  var day = document.getElementById("days");
  
  if (day.value == "3"){
     alert("You Already Have An Email Going Out That Day. Please Select Another Day.");
  }
}
```

```html
<input style="width: 50px; font-size: 17px;" type="number" min="1" autocomplete="off" id="days" name="days" value="1" onchange="daysChange(this.days)" required />
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, you have to get value out of the HTMLInput:

```
if (day.value === "3")
```

Also good point, is that the value of the input is type string, I believe, you need type integer, so using a shorthand property for parseInt:

```
if (day.value|0 === 3)
```

Is much more pretty.